# Set background color in qt

Tags: qt

I have a `QGraphicsScene`. In that scene I have a rects and I want to set different colors in that rects.

**My code is**

```
QGraphicsScene* scene;
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
QGraphicsView* view;
view = new QGraphicsView(this);
view->setGeometry(x, y, mapColumns * min_height_size, mapRows * min_width_size);
view->setScene(scene);

for(int i=0; i<mapRows; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<mapColumns; ++j){
        if (j == 0) {
            y = 20;
        }
        if(map.getCell(i,j).getTerrain() == Cell::forest) {
            scene->addRect(x,y,min_height_size,min_width_size);
            scene->setPalette(Qt::green);  //but it didn't work
            y += min_width_size;
        } else if(map.getCell(i,j).getTerrain() == Cell::mountain){
            scene->addRect(x,y,min_height_size,min_width_size);
            scene->setPalette(Qt::blue);   //but it didn't work
            y += min_width_size;
        } else if(map.getCell(i,j).getTerrain() == Cell::plain) {
            scene->addRect(x,y,min_height_size,min_width_size);
            scene->setPalette(Qt::yellow);  //but it didn't work
            y += min_width_size;
        }
        view->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
    }
     x += min_height_size;
}
}
```

Comment: Actually, you need to set color of rects and not the background.. pls confirm.

Comment: Any code of your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`setBrush()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractgraphicsshapeitem.html#setBrush) function to set the color.

```
QGraphicsRectItem *rect_item1 = scene->addRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
rect_item1->setBrush(Qt::yellow);
QGraphicsRectItem *rect_item2 = scene->addRect(200, 250, 50, 50);
rect_item2->setBrush(QColor(100,50,200));
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set different QPixmap objects into that rects?

Comment: @Mary See [`QGraphicsPixmapItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicspixmapitem.html). Set your `QGraphicsRectItem` as the parent.

Comment: Like this?
QGraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsRectItem * parent = 0);

Comment: @Mary Yes, you can use the constructor to set the parent. `QGraphicsPixmapItem *pix_item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(rect_item1);`

Comment: And then I would use addPixmap() function?

Comment: @Mary No, then you would just use [`setPixmap`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicspixmapitem.html#setPixmap) function to set the pixmap to your item. Read [`setParentItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsitem.html#setParentItem) part of the documentation as well.

Comment: how can I add pixmap item to another pixmap?

Comment: @Mary Try doing it the same way. Set your `QGraphicsPixmapItem ` as the parent.

Comment: This is my code.Am I correct?
map->addWarrior(Warrior::Archer, Warrior::Black, x, y);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *warrior = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap1);
    warrior->setPixmap(QPixmap("res/cohart.gif"));
    warrior->setOffset(x, y);

Comment: @Mary If `pixmap1` is a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` then it seems fine to me. If it's just a `QPixmap` object, then you need to set a parent.

Comment: It's a QGraphiscPixmapItem,but it doesn't help me.

Comment: It's cleaning my all map,and then it's drawing the warrior on bottom right part of QGraphicsScene.

Comment: @Mary You should open a new question and explain the problem, what you tried, the results you got and the results you are trying to achieve. It's really hard to make out what you are trying to do this way.

Comment: I'm tried, but I'm in block,I cant open new question(((